# Why does pivot_wider either read single values as duplicates or create a wide-and-long tibble (without merging rows)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, tidyverse

I browsed through most of the related questions posted here, but none seemed to be the same issue that I am facing. From what I've read, the issues already posted here are related to duplicate values in long-form data (lacking unique identifiers) which result in wide-form data with list-cols, and this is usually fixed by creating a dummy variable column which is a string of unique numbers. I've tried all the different solutions that I saw, but none of them solved my issue, which is why I decided to post this question.

### The Data

I have a long-form table of various plant species (and their counts and layer) found in different plots:

```
> rep_example[1:15,]
   Point   Species Number Layer
1    P03 Lari_deci     21     C
2    P03 Quer_rope     17     C
3    P03 Pinu_sylv      5     C
4    P03 Sorb_aucu      3     U
5    P03 Betu_pend      1     C
6    P03 Acer_pseu      1     U
7    P06 Quer_rope     28     C
8    P06 Pinu_sylv     28     C
9    P06 Popu_trem      6     C
10   P06 Lari_deci      3     C
11   P07 Fagu_sylv    110     C
12   P07 Pinu_sylv     20     C
13   P07 Pice_abie      5     C
14   P07 Quer_rope      3     C
15   P07 Betu_pend      1     C
```

```
> dput(rep_example[1:15,])
structure(list(Point = c("P03", "P03", "P03", "P03", "P03", "P03", 
"P06", "P06", "P06", "P06", "P07", "P07", "P07", "P07", "P07"
), Species = c("Lari_deci", "Quer_rope", "Pinu_sylv", "Sorb_aucu", 
"Betu_pend", "Acer_pseu", "Quer_rope", "Pinu_sylv", "Popu_trem", 
"Lari_deci", "Fagu_sylv", "Pinu_sylv", "Pice_abie", "Quer_rope", 
"Betu_pend"), Number = c("21", "17", "5", "3", "1", "1", "28", 
"28", "6", "3", "110", "20", "5", "3", "1"), Layer = c("C", "C", 
"C", "U", "C", "U", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"
)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

### The Ideal Result

I wish to create a wide form of this table by having the different `Species` names as columns and having just one row per `Layer` per `Point`:

```
> rep_example_ideal
  Point Layer Lari_deci Quer_rope Pinu_sylv Sorb_aucu Betu_pend Acer_pseu
1   P03     C        21        17         5         0         1         0
2   P03     U         0         0         0         3         0         1
3   P06     C         3        28        28         0         0         0
4   P06     U         0         0         0         0         0         0
5   P07     C         0         3        20         1         1         0
6   P07     U         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

```
> dput(rep_example_ideal)
structure(list(Point = c("P03", "P03", "P06", "P06", "P07", "P07"
), Layer = c("C", "U", "C", "U", "C", "U"), Lari_deci = c("21", 
"0", "3", "0", "0", "0"), Quer_rope = c("17", "0", "28", "0", 
"3", "0"), Pinu_sylv = c("5", "0", "28", "0", "20", "0"), Sorb_aucu = c("0", 
"3", "0", "0", "1", "0"), Betu_pend = c("1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
"0"), Acer_pseu = c("0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

### The Problem Code

This is the code I am using to create the wide table:

```
rep_example %>% group_by(Point, Layer) %>% 
  mutate(Number = as.numeric(Number)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(rn = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Point, Layer, rn), names_from = Species, values_from = Number)
```

```
# A tibble: 172 x 17
# Groups:   Point, Layer [57]
   Point Layer    rn Lari_deci Quer_rope Pinu_sylv Sorb_aucu Betu_pend Acer_pseu Popu_trem
   <chr> <chr> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 P03   C         1        21        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
 2 P03   C         2        NA        17        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
 3 P03   C         3        NA        NA         5        NA        NA        NA        NA
 4 P03   U         1        NA        NA        NA         3        NA        NA        NA
 5 P03   C         4        NA        NA        NA        NA         1        NA        NA
 6 P03   U         2        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         1        NA
 7 P06   C         1        NA        28        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
 8 P06   C         2        NA        NA        28        NA        NA        NA        NA
 9 P06   C         3        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         6
10 P06   C         4         3        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# ... with 162 more rows, and 7 more variables: Fagu_sylv <dbl>, Pice_abie <dbl>,
#   Abie_alba <dbl>, Fran_alnu <dbl>, Tili_cord <dbl>, Alnu_glut <dbl>, Quer_rubr <dbl>
```

1. I am using `mutate(rn = 1:n())` to create a dummy variable `rn`, in order to ensure unique identifiers. Rows with the same value for Week and Point aren't being merged, and instead show up as separate rows. I tried using different forms of `group_by()` but these don't make a difference, while explicitly stating `id_cols` in the `pivot_wider()` leads to issue #2 below.
2. When I do not use `mutate(rn = 1:n())`, the wide data produced consists of list-cols *even though* the list length is 1 (all other questions posted here resulted in longer list-cols, i.e., duplicates) and the combination of `Week` and `Point` provides a unique ID. However, the above problem of rows not being merged is fixed in this method.

```
rep_example %>% group_by(Point, Layer) %>% 
  mutate(Number = as.numeric(Number)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Point, Layer), names_from = Species, values_from = Number)
```

```
# A tibble: 57 x 16
# Groups:   Point, Layer [57]
   Point Layer Lari_deci Quer_rope Pinu_sylv Sorb_aucu Betu_pend Acer_pseu Popu_trem Fagu_sylv
   <chr> <chr> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
 1 P03   C     <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
 2 P03   U     <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>   
 3 P06   C     <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>   
 4 P07   C     <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <dbl [1]>
 5 P07   U     <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
 6 P08   C     <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>   
 7 P08   U     <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
 8 P10   U     <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
 9 P10   C     <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
10 P11   C     <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>    <NULL>   
# ... with 47 more rows, and 6 more variables: Pice_abie <list>, Abie_alba <list>,
#   Fran_alnu <list>, Tili_cord <list>, Alnu_glut <list>, Quer_rubr <list>
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

The `pivot_wider` is working in some other code I tried with a different part of the data. This particular issue has remained unresolved, and I'd highly appreciate any sort of help!!!

Thanks!

Comment: This is not what you want? `rep_example %>%group_by(Point, Species) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = Number)` ?

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah! That seems to be exactly what I wanted. Somehow, grouping by Species before `pivot_wider` seemed counterintuitive, but that is apparently what had to be done. It works with my original code using `mutate(rn = 1:n())` as well (just a matter of unique ID). However, slightly unrelated, there seems to be a problem if I use `mutate(Number = as.numeric(Number))`---I get the following error after the `pivot_wider()` function: `Error: Can't convert <character> to <double>.` Is this because `as.numeric()` changes the default tibble formatting for operations to work?

Comment: Is there any reason why it produces list-cols even though there aren't duplicates, i.e., list-cols are of length 1?

Comment: I think there should be atleast one value which is repeated. Can you check in the output tibble if there is any value that is like `dbl [2]` or higher?

Comment: @RonakShah Ah! Yes, I see just one list which is of length 2, while all others are 1 (or 0 for NULLs). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a sequence column with `rowid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(rn = rowid(Point, Species)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = Number, 
       values_fill = list(Number = '0'))
```

---

If we want all the combinations, use `complete`

```
df1 %>% 
   complete(Point, Layer, fill = list(Number = '0')) %>%
   fill(Species) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = Number,  
         values_fill = list(Number = '0'))
# A tibble: 6 x 11
#  Point Layer Lari_deci Quer_rope Pinu_sylv Betu_pend Sorb_aucu Acer_pseu Popu_trem Fagu_sylv Pice_abie
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#1 P03   C     21        17        5         1         0         0         0         0         0        
#2 P03   U     0         0         0         0         3         1         0         0         0        
#3 P06   C     3         28        28        0         0         0         6         0         0        
#4 P06   U     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0        
#5 P07   C     0         3         20        1         0         0         0         110       5        
#6 P07   U     0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first suggestion works. However, I think Ronak Shah's suggestion is better suited, because I realise that the issue was simply because I didn't group by Species. On the other hand, I tried your suggestion using `complete`, but got the following error: `Error: Can't convert <character> to <list>.` Could you please elaborate what `complete` does, since we are also using `values_fill = list(Number = '0')` in the same code?

Comment: @rikudoukarthik If you check my first option.  It is exactly doing the group_by row_number

Comment: Oh, I see now! That code is indeed terse. Thank you. I'm still confused with your second suggestion though. Could you please clarify what `complete` does?

Comment: @rikudoukarthik I find that some combinations with 0 value row were missing inthe first case which you showed in the expected output.  The `complete` is to create additional combinations so that the 0 rows are also kept.

Comment: What is the reason the unique ID `mutate(rn = rowid(Point, Species))` is not required when using `complete`?

Comment: @rikudoukarthik It is just that with `complete`, you get more rows and for the example, there is no duplicates for Point, Species.  It is better to have the `rowid` as a general case